# sum values of same key names in a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have this `dictionary` that has an arbitrary number of keys which are dates, I'm trying to `sum up` the income of each key, my problem is I don't the number of keys at any given point.

Here is the dictionary

```
        Tax_table = {
            "2021-01-16": {
                "Income": 400.19,
                ...other key, values...
            },
            "2021-01-18": {
                "Income": 578
                ...other key, values...
            },
            "2021-01-21": {
                "Income": 1877,
                ....other key, values...
            }
        }
```

Is there a way to sum up all incomes of the table?

Comment: The dictionary you have provided appears to have only one income for each date.  What do you mean by "sum up the income of each key?" You may need to provide more detail about the other entries in your dictionary.

Comment: Do you just want the total sum of all the `Income` keys? Could you post sample output you expect, and your current code for some context?

Comment: If that's the case, do `s = sum(val['Income'] for val in Tax_table.values())`

Comment: Made it look easy there @costaparas, Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to sum up all incomes of the table, the below code will work:

```
total_sum = 0
for i in Tax_table:
    total_sum = total_sum + Tax_table[i]['Income']
    
print(total_sum)
```